# Upgraded version of Opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight

What are the extra feature added to open daylight stable/beryllium version?
And what are the architectural changes between Open daylight helium and Open daylight beryllium?

Comment: hi, check this link ,https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_rLr6so6DZ8cXRJczlJSVBzOE0/view?pref=2&pli=1

Comment: Thank You! But I couldn't find new features added to beryllium.

Answer (score 0):

Helium and Beryllium are two major releases, and there was Lithium released in between. If your question is whether to go ahead with Beryllium or Helium, definitely go with Beryllium. Almost the entire architecture changed - with Karaf based deployments and the move to MD-SAL from AD-SAL.

Have a look at https://www.opendaylight.org/odlbe Note that this is comparing with Lithium. Helium is an older version. So have more changes, obviously.